# Install breaks on Step 2 in XAMPP for Windows

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

http://content.screencast.com/users/inulled/folders/Snagit/media/8bb54c95-f131-4d55-a3e2-368c1f686a80/03.22.2013-16.16.08.png

As you can tell from the image above, something is going wrong. I am using the latest verison XAMPP under Windows 7. I have recieved this same error on my win8 system and also in WAMPP on both computers. Does anybody know why I'm getting this error?